# Firebase Chat App Image Download

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

I am writing a Chat Application. I can send Pictures and show them via Picasso in an ImageView. But how can I save the Picture to my Device?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the url to the file then you can download the image using any http library you like. Or if you want to do all the work yourself you can implement it using java's standard networking libraries. 
Personally I recommend using Retrofit but there are tons of libraries out there that can help you easily download files.

Once you have the file you save it to the android device like any other file by using either external or internal storage. Here is a guide for that https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html .